# Git specific workflow

Tags: git, gitlab

My team and i have started using git to keep track of all the changes in our programs.
Our repository is as follows:

- main branch
- Various branches each with the name of the order the customer buys.

Our workflow is as follows:

- Me and the colleagues in the office create the new branches from the master branch.
- We modify the program if the order has new functionalities.
- The colleagues in production works with those branches and when they find something wrong they push the commits with the changes.
- Then, all together, we discuss everyday if the commits pushed on those branches are good, if yes then we cherry pick them into the main branch, so the next order will have those changes. (we don't merge the branches into main because not all the commits needs to go into main, e.g. configuration of inputs and outputs)

The problem with this workflow is that if we have more than one order that is being changed in production, we'll have different changes cherry picked into main, but the other branches will not have the same changes unless we cherry pick them on every branch.
Should i just merge the main branch in all the branches i'm working on everyday or there's a better workflow?

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-known workflow called the [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) that you may be interested in. This workflow involves creating a separate branch for each feature or task, making changes to that branch, and then merging it back into the main branch when the feature or task is complete.

Your workflow is similar to this, but with some differences. For instance, cherry-picking is not typically used to merge changes back to the main branch since it is an advanced technique used for maintaining long-lived branches. In addition, feature branches have a short lifespan and are created to be merged, so they should be deleted after merging.

You may be concerned about situations where changes are merged into the main branch but other branches do not have the changes made from other feature branches. In this case, people usually use a rebase strategy to keep all feature branches up to date with changes in the main branch. This can help prevent merge conflicts and ensure that all changes are properly integrated..

Comment: The problem i have with Feature Branch Workflow is that, for how we're working, we have branches that will never get merged in the main branch.
If we use the workflow you suggest, we can't have different branches for every order we make for the customer, and that's not what we want.

Comment: Your workflow seems to resemble an environment strategy, where a new branch is created for each order, similar to how environment branches are created based on different environments such as production or staging. In the environment strategy, long-lived branches are created based on the environment, whereas in your workflow, new branches are created for each order.

Comment: It works the same way. Your order branches should rebase the main branch as well.

Comment: Exactly, u got the idea.
It works the same way as the feature branch u mean? Or the same way as the environment strategy?

Comment: I mean environment strategy. You could borrow the idea from that.

Comment: Sorry for the question but, could you send me some link that explains this workflow? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html#environment-branches-with-gitlab-flow hope this help.